# Xdebug and Netbeans are not communicating with each other

Tags: xampp, netbeans-7, xdebug

I have spent a couple of days surfing the internet to find an answer to my question. I have tried everything I could but have been unsuccessful thus far in solving this problem.  Netbeans keeps giving **Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)**.

I am using the following software:

- XAMPP Version 1.8.1.
- Windows 7
- Netbeans IDE 7.2.1
- Xdebug 2.2.1

I installed the latest version according via the wizard for the xdebug.org site (http://xdebug.org/wizard.php). Xdebug is working according to phpinfo().The HMTL output in my browser (Firefox 17.0.1) shows xdebug code. However this is not communicated back to netbeans. Using Netstat via command prompt (Run -> cmd.exe) shows that there is a TCP connection on port 9000. However ,  nothing is reported back in Netbeans.

I have tried several different alternatives, for example:

- Installing a similar IDE, Eclipse PDT. Eclipse shows that Xdebug is
  working. However, because Eclipse is lacking functions I need I
  wanted to use Netbeans.
- Installing Netbeans on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
  Still the same problem. Netbeans not working (waiting for
  connection). Also output in browsers shows that Xdebug is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I install on a new Linux machine: "php xdebug" and netbeans 
I run these simple steps and I've always managed to corect integration of xdebug on netbeans.
So with the data you provide, I can only help you solve, the half of your problem. 
 **Allowing you to connect on Linux machines**:

*Installation with pecl:*

> # apt-get install php5-dev php-pear 
>   # pecl install xdebug

*Or direct installation:*

> # apt-get install php5-xdebug

find the library:

> # find / -name 'xdebug.so' 
>  
>   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so

Edit phi.ini file:

> ...
>
> zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so 
>   xdebug.remote_enable=1 
>   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
>   xdebug.remote_mode=req 
>   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 
>   xdebug.remote_port=9000
>
> ...

*Restart web-server in your case: Apache*

> $ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

---

*According to what you have posted:*

> Installing Netbeans on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

*I have used the installation method "apt-get" for distributions ".deb".
If you are using a distribution ".rpm" can do the same with "yum"*

*Many of these commands are surely simplified within the xampp. 

But if you running this commands from console will not affect the final result.*

---

Another important note about Windows's machines and  Linux's machines, 
**You should check that your firewall rules are allowing to establish a connection from netbeans to xdebug.**

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. I got it working in windows, however the way why I got it working is very strange. I had to set the port to "9001" and the proxy to "localhost". This is strange because the port in php.ini is set at 9000.

Comment: I will give Ubuntu a new try. B.T.W. I installed LAMP via Tasksel instead of XAMPP and followed the instruction on the Xdebug wizard site. I edited the xdebug.ini ($ sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini) file in the way as you did with php.ini. I added "xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug"
to the file. I didn't install UFW on Ubuntu at first so that wasn't a problem. I will now because a firewall is always a good security measure.

Comment: Netbeans and xdebug on Ubuntu is now up and running. Same solution as with windows, setting the port to 9001 did the trick. Very strange.

Comment: good work! On the windows surely the port is reserved to another process
You could try to identify the conflict with [**TCPView**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) tool,

or from console with [**netstat**](http://www.computerhope.com/netstat.htm) or want to find a mathematical answer to your problem could use [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see each packet processing

Comment: There is no conflict with the ports as far as I can see. However, it is strange that setting a netbeans project to another port solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for people using Ubuntu this might help.

```
OS Version = Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS; Codename: trusty
PHP Version = PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:17:32) 
Apache Version = Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

Procedure

> 1. Install xdebug for php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

> 2. Open php.ini and add the following lines below (usually sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On;
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000;
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp";
```

> 3. Restart apache and your good to go

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Note 1: I have not tried doing this without firefox add-on for xdebug, so if after doing the procedure above and still to no avail, download the add-on for firefox [Easy Xdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/)*

*Note 2: I did not touch the PHP Configuration of Netbeans*

*Note 3: I did not touch xdebug.ini*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very well documented. I did already solve it with a while back, but as you mentioned it might help others.