# Netbeans Xdebug installing +PHP+ ubuntu Operating system

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xdebug and Netbeans are not communicating with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880415/xdebug-and-netbeans-are-not-communicating-with-each-other)

How to implement `xdebug` in `netbeans`. I searched lot and I have done some stuff in apache  `php.ini`

```
zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Am using `Ubuntu` OS.

`Xdebug` is mainly using for debug complex php code.( `for loop / foreach`)

Right now when I click on debug project `netbeans`  footer status showing searching for xdebug connection and its not ending not ending means connection failed.

I think you get what I want.

Please help me.

Comment: When you start debugging from netbeans does a browser window open with the project you are working on?

Answer (score 13):

Recently I have configured `xdebug` with `netbeans` in `ubuntu`.

Here are the following steps for you to installing and configuring `xdebug` with `netbeans`

1) Go to this page and install the Firefox plugin:

```
   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/
```

2) Install xdebug using command below from command prompt(terminal)

```
   sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

3) then open xdebug.ini from terminal:

```
gedit /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

4) Copy the only line there. (which should be look like:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so).
```

5) open the php.ini file with superuser permissions using this command

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

6) paste the line you copied from the `xdebug.ini` along with the following four lines into your `php.ini` file:

paste the copied line here

```
                      xdebug.remote_enable=On;
                      xdebug.remote_host="localhost;"
                      xdebug.remote_port=9000;
                      xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp";
```

7) It's done!!! just need to restart your apache:

use following command for that:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now simply open project in `netbeans` and press `ctrl+F5` or click `debug>debug` project 
from menu.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: in step4) I had to sudo gedit /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini