# not able to debug eclipse helios 3.6

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-3.6

I have the following scenario:

xdebug 2.0.0rc1-5.1.2
Eclipse Helios 
php 5.1.6

I am trying to debug a php application on eclipse but it doesn't stops on breakpoints. The browser is initallized correctly. I think versions of xdebug , eclipse helios and php are compatible. I've removed all breakpoints and i have created it again. xdebug appears in phpinfo configured as extension.

Anyone knows why it doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

xdebug details in phpinfo:

Version  2.0.0RC1

```
Supported protocols Revision 
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol  $Revision: 1.99 $  
GDB - GNU Debugger protocol  $Revision: 1.81 $  
PHP3 - PHP 3 Debugger protocol  $Revision: 1.20 $  

Directive Local Value Master Value 
xdebug.allowed_clients no value no value 
xdebug.auto_trace Off Off 
xdebug.collect_includes On On 
xdebug.collect_params Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return Off Off 
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off 
xdebug.default_enable On On 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE no value no value 
xdebug.dump.ENV no value no value 
xdebug.dump.FILES no value no value 
xdebug.dump.GET no value no value 
xdebug.dump.POST no value no value 
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value no value 
xdebug.dump.SERVER no value no value 
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value no value 
xdebug.dump_globals On On 
xdebug.dump_once On On 
xdebug.dump_undefined Off Off 
xdebug.extended_info On On 
xdebug.idekey francescjp no value 
xdebug.manual_url http://www.php.net http://www.php.net 
xdebug.max_nesting_level 100 100 
xdebug.profiler_aggregate Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_append Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_enable Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir /tmp /tmp 
xdebug.profiler_output_name crc32 crc32 
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off 
xdebug.remote_enable On On 
xdebug.remote_handler ”dbgp” ”dbgp” 
xdebug.remote_host 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 
xdebug.remote_log no value no value 
xdebug.remote_mode req req 
xdebug.remote_port 9000 9000 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars Off Off 
xdebug.show_mem_delta Off Off 
xdebug.trace_format 0 0 
xdebug.trace_options 0 0 
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp /tmp 
xdebug.trace_output_name crc32 crc32 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth 2 2
```

Comment: Is the PHP application running on the same host as you develop? (Where eclipse runs)? Do you have a firewall running that blocks port 9000?

Comment: Yes but I have especified an exception that permits use this port..

Comment: Are you familiar with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)?

Comment: Yes. Good idea. I will see what happens with it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if you are using the correct version of Xdebug? The wizzard will help you pick the wright version http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php.

I don't know which OS you using but I guess it is Windows. I had a similar problem with netbeans on Unbuntu and Windows ([Xdebug and Netbeans are not communicating with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880415/xdebug-and-netbeans-are-not-communicating-with-each-other)). Because Netbeans and Eclipse appear to share a lot of common elements this might help. Set you port number to 9001 inside eclipse.

**EDIT:More info**

This is my configuration:

> ```
> XAMPP Version 1.8.1.
> Windows 7
> Eclipse PDT 32bit version
> Xdebug 2.2.1
> ```

My suggestion is update everything to the latest version or to use the exact same configuration.

In my php.ini file (C:\xampp\php\php.ini) I have the following settings. You can access php.ini via the Controle panel -> Config -> PHP (php.ini).

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.remote_port="9000"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
;xdebug.remote_mode=reg
;xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

AND turnoff report zend debug in php.ini

```
; This setting is on by default.
report_zend_debug = 0
```

Xdebug Configuration inside Eclipse:

Start Eclipse -> Explorer window -> File -> Properties -> PHP -> PHP debug -> Select under default settings Xdebug instead of Zend. (If needed configure: Xdebug to port 9000).

Comment: I have checked that I use the correct version of xdebug. I will try to change port number. I will tell how it works.

Comment: I have changed the port on eclipse. but the result is the same

Comment: I have used the xdebug wizard and tell me the following: •Xdebug installed: Only as PHP extension! and syas also The compiler (MS VC6) that this PHP was build with, is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a version that was built with MS VC9. The version that i use of xdebug is not served in vc9

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows, linux or Mac. If you are using Windows I would suggest installing XAMPP.

Comment: Did you comment out any Zend Optimizer in php.ini?

Comment: Yes I've comented all lines

Comment: I have edited my answer to include my php.ini file and settings inside Eclipse.

Comment: I use an vc6 debug version. I will try to use vc9 and check what happens. I'll tell you. Thanks a lot.